# Core plot- prevent zooming/scaling of plot to show full axes range

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, core-plot

I have a y-axis boundary from 0 to 100 and an x axis boundary from 0 to 10.  When I plot data points (0,85) and (1,86), only the portion of the plot with data points is shown.  I understand how this is useful, but in my case I need the entire axis shown, unscaled.  Is there a way to show the complete axes, without zooming to the data points?  Thanks for your help.

[image]

Comment: try to remove "scaleToFitPlots".. and set xRange and yRange directly; ..or… call -scaleToFitPlots: and then set the xRange afterwards.

Comment: Got it.  Had to remove scaleToFitPlots.  If you make this an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is more a hint than an answer.. but, as I already said in comments:

- you can try to remove "scaleToFitPlots" and set xRange and yRange directly;

or..

- call -scaleToFitPlots: and then set the xRange afterwards