# How do i control the zooming / scaling of the scatter plot graph to show both axes

Tags: ios, scale, core-plot, zooming, scatter-plot

I am trying to draw a line graph using the scatter plot in the core-plot library for ios.

Being a noob at this library, I was using an example [from here as a reference](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13271/how-to-draw-graphs-with-core-plot-part-2)

While I am able to get to a point where I have my line graphs working, I find that in case of datasets where the y axis data is grouped together and much greater than 0, the graph zooms / scales to a point where the x-axis itself is no longer visible.

Refer this graph:

[image]

I would prefer my graph to always look like this:

[image]

I am using `scaleToFitPlots` to scale the graph and my understanding is that using that function has this effect as per this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16953396/core-plot-prevent-zooming-scaling-of-plot-to-show-full-axes-range).

If I do not use `scaleToFitPlots` function, does that mean I will need to manually calculate my axis scale / intervals etc manually based on the set of values being plotted?

Is there any better alternate? The above answered question also mentions using -scaleToFitPlots. Does anyone know what is meant by that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you always want the axes to cross at the same place, use the `orthogonalCoordinateDecimal` property. It defaults to zero for both axes, but you can change that if you want. If the crossing point is outside the visible range after calling `-scaleToFitPlots:`, you can adjust the `location` and `length` of the `yRange` afterwards to extend the range to cover the crossing point.

If you don't care where they cross but always want the axes visible, use `axisConstraints`. Several of the Core Plot example apps demonstrate how to do this. For example, this code will lock the x-axis to the bottom of the plot area:

```
x.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:0.0];
```

You can also use a relative offset to do things like keep an axis in the middle of the plot area.

Comment: Thanks. The axisConstraints does meet my needs for now. But the other points are good to know as well